# uncontrolled movement in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have really no idea what to do in my situation: I have given a Rigidbody property to my object (cube), and after that it just moves chaotically all over the walkable area (plane). That happens even without some scripts: it just starts after object becomes a rigidbody. 
I'll be very thankful for any help

Comment: I think that this question should be on the [gamedev stackexchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) network

Comment: Does the plane have a rigidbody as well? If so, make sure that they object doesn't start inside of the plane. Checkout [Unity rigidbody tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/rigidbodies)

Comment: @Wndrr This question is not better suited to game dev. This is a technical problem, not a design problem (although code questions are not explicitly off topic). Always check a site's How to Ask before recommending that a user migrate their question there.

Comment: As he himself stated "That happens even without some scripts". This is not a programming question. Plus, you CAN ask programming on the gamedev stackexchange network when they are gamedev-related as per third line of the first bullet lies on the [what topics can I sk](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page. Rigidbbodis are a gamedev-specific topic and not really closely related to general programming so i believe this question is not a good fit on SO since it doesn't contain code and definitely wont.
Sorry if I sound aggressive, but I did check the site's how to ask.